# How to call the image in the product view magento?

Tags: image, magento, fancybox

I want to call the image that loads into the larger view area of the magento product page.

In the product view page, I have more view images when clicked, it shows the image in the larger view, not in default pop up window. I want to call the full size image of whatever the image is loaded in the larger view area. Can someone tell me how do I do it?

I did some search and found

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(163, 100);
```

But this gets only the image which was there by default. I want to be able to call any image that comes in the larger view area.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
```

this will get you the image on product view page.

Comment: It returns the base image ONLY where as I want to call every image that comes up when the more view image is clicked.For example on product "shirt", I have base image "A" and I have more view images "B", "C" and "D". With the code you provided above, it only calls the base image "A". What if the user clicks on more view images "B", "C" or "D"?

Comment: foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) { echo var_export($image->getUrl()); } , this will give you all the images for the product

Comment: Thanks you for your response but it gives me the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getMediaGalleryImages() on a non-object". And actually I do not want all the images. I want to have the image which is on the product large view area. And the image changes there as the user clicks on the moreview image. So the code I am looking should give me the url for more view images "B" , "C" and "D" only when they are active.

Comment: the error is because you must call getMediaGalleryImages() by using product object. i think you have to use javascript to get the selected image and its url when the user clicks to view it.

Comment: I am very new to magento and have no knowledge of javascript. I am trying to use fancybox and cannot not do it. Will really appreciate if you could help me with this.Thank you so much

Comment: you need to study javascript and then look into how to use fancybox and get the selected image url. i will give you hint how to get the url in javascript. first make sure that you are viewing the magento website in google chrome. now when you click on image and a larger image appears, then you right click on the larger image and select "inspect element". this will show a panel at the bottom of google chrome, showing the image element tag. note the id of this tag. now you use javascript to get the url. for example "document.getElementById('tagname').src".

Comment: Awesome.Thank you. I did the following and now its working.<a class="fullscreen" href="#image" onclick="document.getElementById('image').style.width='100%'; return false; " > <img  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/zoom_full.jpg') ?>" 
            alt="<?php echo $this->__('Full Screen') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Full Screen') ?>" /></a>

Answer (score 1):

ok I think this might save ur trouble. ITs Damn easy

Lets say ur main image area is `<img id="main-image" src="main-image.jpg" />`

```
 <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
<li>
    <a class="grouped_elements" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(260,null) ?>"
       title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" rel="group1">

        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(70,null) ?>"
             width="70"  alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
    </a>
</li>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    jQuery("a.grouped_elements").click(function(){

           $('#main-image').attr('src', this.attr('href'));

    });

//]]>
</script>
```

Hope this should help ...

Answer (score 0):

I think u must check the file

**app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view**

& its declared as in the

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
```

this file gives u the Main Image & also the Gallery Images. of course u'll get only enabled images. 
so What I understand from the subsequent comments. u need these images in a fancybox. there has to be a slideshow thing previou next etc. right??

ok Here it is what u can do. Create a  new file under

**app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\fancy.media.phtml**

(or u can use ur theme folder instead of  base/default)

in ur **catalog.xml** add this block under

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>

<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="fancy.media" template="catalog/product/view/fancy.media.phtml"/>
```

now in media.phtml u'll get all the images & there URLs. code the fancybox & pass the image url to it. & 
& yeah don't forget to call this block in ur product page i.e. 
**app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml**

by `echo $this->getChilHtml('fancy.media')`

I hope this must solve problem

**UPDATE:**

try this in fancy.media.phtml:

```
 <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
    <li>
        <a class="grouped_elements" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(260,null) ?>"
           title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" rel="group1">

            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(70,null) ?>"
                 width="70"  alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
        </a>
    </li>
<?php   endforeach;     ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();

//]]>
</script>
```

Please refer to the Docs of fancybox, [fancybox how to](http://fancybox.net/howto)

I think ur requirement is if somebody clicks on the More-views on product page it must get open in fancybox. Right?? so u can place this code in media.phtml also. no need to create a new file & no need to edit the catalog.xml.

If u make this working then feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: I will try this out. Sounds like better solution.WHAT DO I HAVE TO DO IN FANCY.MEDIA.PHTML?I MEAN WHAT WILL BE THE CODE IN THAT FILE? Thank you. I will let you know.

Comment: I trie this and result was like from one of the plugins and doesnt solve the issue. It lists all the more view images . When clicked on it, it pops up in lightbox.I am looking for something like magento extension's product page

Comment: @squizeers can u give me link what exactly u want ?? u mean when u click on more view images that must be replace the Main large image with the one that u clicked??

Comment: this is the pagw where the image pop up functionality ius working the way i want to have in my site. magentocommerce DOT com SLASH magento-connect SLASH site-management SLASH catalog SLASH idealo-connect.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result by adding a button on media.phtml

```
<a class="fullscreen" href="#image" onclick="document.getElementById('image').style.width='100%'; return false; " > <img  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/zoom_full.jpg') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Full Screen') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Full Screen') ?>" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">  j(document).ready(function() {
j(".fullscreen").fancybox({ 'transitionIn': 'fade', 'transitionOut':
'none', 'overlayColor': '#fff', 'overlayOpacity':1,
'hideOnOverlayClick':false }); </script>
```